# Setting up ADLDS and managing it with internal ADLDS users

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, ad-lds

I configured `ADLDS` according to this [blog post](http://sharepoint-2010-world.blogspot.com/2011/03/installing-active-directory-lightweight.html). I went further and followed [this Microsoft article](http://technet.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/cc816642%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) about allowing internal users to access `ADLDS` thru `ADSI Edit` but whatever I do i get access denied (just asking me continuously for login and password). Is there some magic thing I'm missing. I can login with Administrative account from the system. Just the internal logins and passwords that I set according to descriptions can't login.

Any magic I forgot to use? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple. Login as `CN=Admin,CN=....,DC=COMPANY,DC=PL` (full path to ADLDS where account exists). I was using `"Admin"` or other account names without providing full path which I guess was assuming Local account and didn't let me in.